# Android studio components installation failed: access denied

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

Failed to complete operation using com.android.tools.idea.sdk.install.patch.PatchInstaller, retrying with com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller while installing google repository in android studio

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this installation we have to use administrator login.